# Julia - Modules and Parallelism

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I'm having trouble understanding how to use worker processes along with modules. I'll try to explain my difficulty simply.

I have on my main process (process 1) a module, `module A`.

On worker processes ,I have `module B`, which is supposed to handle numerous complicated calculations (as is often the case with parallel workers).

The problem is that it seems as if `module A` needs to be defined on the workers...

The problem is that `module A` is much larger than `module B`, it includes thousands of lines of code, but `module B` only uses around 15 short functions.

Is there any workaround so I can make my main worker have access to `module A` but the workers access to `module B` but be able to call workers from methods in `module A`, and make them run functions defined in their `module B`? For example, there could be a method in `module B` called `calculate_stuff()`.

The structure I was hoping to achieve is something like:

```
module A # main worker process using this module 
    function call_worker_and_calculate()
        remotecall_fetch(calculate_stuff, 2)
    end 

    export call_worker_and_calculate
end

module B # worker process 2 is using this module  
    function calculate_stuff()
        # some stuff 
    end 

    export calculate_stuff 
end
```

This particular example would return the error message:

```
julia> A.call_worker_and_calculate()
ERROR: On worker 2:
UndefVarError: A not defined
```

Comment: You could change your functions in `A` to accepting the function to execute as an argument, e.g., `call_worker_and_calculate(f) = remotecall_fetch(f, 2)` and call ist like `A.call_worker_and_calculate(B.calculate_stuff)`. In any case, `B` must be in the path or defined on each worker using `@everywhere`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is odd (I can't reproduce it with your code, what version do you use?). So I'm not sure this answers your question.

If you want to use a name from a module `B` in another module `A`, you must `import` or `using` module `B` in `A`.

For this to work, `B` must be in a path contained in the Julia variable `LOAD_PATH` or defined on all workers with `@everywhere` *before* the definition of `A`, e.g.,

```
@everywhere module B  # defined on all workers
    function calculate_stuff()
        # do stuff 
    end 

    export calculate_stuff 
end

module A # only defined on the main worker process
    using B  # introduces calculate_stuff into A's scope because it is exported in B
    function call_worker_and_calculate()
        remotecall_fetch(calculate_stuff, 2)    
    end 

    export call_worker_and_calculate
end
```

Then `A.call_worker_and_calculate()` works and `A` is also not defined on other workers:

```
julia> remotecall_fetch(whos,2)
    From worker 2:                               B   4537 bytes  Module
    From worker 2:                            Base  34048 KB     Module
    From worker 2:                            Core  12482 KB     Module
    From worker 2:                            Main  40807 KB     Module
```

Comment: Excellent thank you! I gave up yesterday and threw away the test code I had so Im not 100% sure where I went wrong, but Id guess I didnt bring module `B` correctly into the scope of `A` , i.e I didnt do the `using B` part inside `A`. You just saved me loading a 3000 line module onto 7 cores, along with adding 15 useless methods into the main module